# Display an alert/message on publish in Sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore, publish

I need to display a warning message to the author before they publish. With the code below, I get the following exception:

> Object Reference not set to the instance of an object exception.
>   Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse is null.

How can I fix this? Or is there a different way to do this?

```
public class PublishPipeline : 
Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction
{
    public override void Process(PublishItemContext context)
    {
        Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("This will publish to the production site!");
        base.Process(context);
    }
}


<processor type="MyProject.PublishPipeline, MyAssembly" />
```

Comment: I think it's not the right approach. You should override Sitecore Publish Wizard Form.
Refer:
https://horizontalintegration.blog/2017/12/05/how-to-override-sitecore-publish-wizard-form/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475500/how-to-customize-publish-action-sitecore

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Going with Nikki Punjabi's solution provided above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475500/how-to-customize-publish-action-sitecore